# what makes windows syslistview32 so slow?

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to use syslistview32 as a container to diplay a dataset from db. About 10K records(120+ columns), the db fetch operation very fast,less then 2 seconds.but the marco ListView_InsertItem/ListView_SetItem，very slow. the total loading procedure cost almost 15 seconds(or even more).

what makes the loading processs so slow ? what's the major difference between syslistview32 and sql plus dataview (tsgrid as the spy shows) ? if i insisted in using the syslistview32 ， what should i do to improving the process?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing real code. if the listview is sorted, or you're doing mid-list insertions (or both), things can get very expensive, very fast.

Comment: @WhozCraig what's mid-list insertions?

Comment: Exactly what it sounds like. As you assembling your list placing items anywhere other than the end of the list (which would be an append).

Comment: you mean add a row at any place but the tail of the row index ?@WhozCraig and if so what makes the matters ?

Comment: i have tried just now , I make the ListView_InsertItem parameter index been setted as 0. NO exactly improvment. did i miss something ?

Comment: It can make a difference due to how the list content is managed. And prepending (always insert at the beginning) is probably the worst case. Frankly, if you're pumping that many items in the list I'm surprised you didn't just [virtualize the list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN#virtual-list-view-style) in the first place. In that context you keep the actual data and just provide keys to get it to the listview. No data copying really to speak of. The downshot: You have to maintain the data for the life of the listview.

Comment: Another downshot: you also have to maintain sorting characteristics.

Comment: sound like a relaiable reference of what really blocked me . thank you @WhozCraig

Comment: For large datasets you do need to use the list in virtual mode, I second that

Comment: it works well, 20K records，with owner drawing included,less then 2 seconds,even faster then the SQL/PLUS Grid（to much update messsages) ，memory costs . 9M bytes before , now 27M bytes@WhozCraig   @David Heffeman